# tsc : File C:\Program Files\nodejs\tsc.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system

Tags: javascript, types

I am trying to run a command `tsc` for a `file.ts` as to compile this code to `js` but I fins the below error:

```
tsc : File C:\Program Files\nodejs\tsc.ps1 cannot be loaded because running scripts is disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies at 
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ tsc test.ts
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

and here's a screen shot of my `Editor`:

[image: tsc error]

any one knows how can I solve this error?

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7#powershell-execution-policies

Comment: @UmairKhan thanks for your comment I hope you can let me know the direct answer or small explanation bout this

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`PowerShell` has some [Execution Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7#powershell-execution-policies) which tell `PS` what to do if user tries to execute some code or script.

If the execution policy is [Undefined](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7#undefined), which is mostly the case, the applied policy is [Restricted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7#restricted).

As defined in `Restricted Policy`, all script files execution is prevented.

> Prevents running of all script files, including formatting and configuration files (`.ps1xml`), module script files (`.psm1`), and PowerShell profiles (`.ps1`).

You can check your current execution policy by running this command in `PS` as advised [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7#managing-the-execution-policy-with-powershell).

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy
```

OR

```
Get-ExecutionPolicy -List
```

You can [change execution policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_execution_policies?view=powershell-7#change-the-execution-policy) like

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope CurrentUser
```

Keep in mind

> In Windows Vista and later versions of Windows, to run commands that change the execution policy for the local computer, LocalMachine scope, start `PowerShell` with the **Run as administrator** option.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks you a lot Bro this is really help me and solved my problem...
I understand now :)..

Thanks you so much

Comment: Jesus answer crazy bro so nice thanks haha haha

Comment: blossom awesome, this answer really helped me